# Operación y funciones en PHP con eval()

Tags: php, html

Agradeceria su ayuda con este codigo.
Consiste un recibir una funcion f(x) y una variable x, luego mostrar el resultado y guardar en una variable.

```
<?php
$x=$_POST['Dato1'];

$funcion=$_POST['Funcion'];
$funcion1= str_replace("x", "$x", $funcion);

echo "<br>";
echo "$funcion1";
echo "<br>";
echo '' .eval ("\$funcion1=\"$funcion1\";");
echo "<br>";
echo "$funcion1";
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Cuál es tu pregunta? Aquí no se usa el hacer review del código; con todo gusto ayudamos a resolver problemas específicos. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta y preguntar algo, añadir info y demás, usando el enlace bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas

Comment: PD. eval era una mala idea hace diez años cuando usé PHP. Seguro que quieres usar eval?

Comment: Alfabravo buen dia, me pidieron utilizar eval() pero si existe otra forma me encantaría conocerla.

Comment: Sigues sin contarnos qué problema tiene el código. De nuevo, edita tu pregunta, por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El str_replace no tiene sentido, porque estás remplazando el nombre del parámetro por el dato. Además nunca llamás a la función, como se ve en la tercera linea del siguiente código:

```
<?php
$x=$_POST['Dato1'];
eval('$funcion = '. $_POST['Funcion'] .";");
$resultado = $funcion($x);
echo $resultado;
```

(Funciona si se recibe una función anónima)

Comment: De paso probá enviando el dato concatenado con esto: `'datoValue'.(function(){var_dump(glob("/*")); return "";})()` para que veas por qué no es buena idea usar eval.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu código, me permitió llegar a la solución. El str_replace lo utilizaba para cambiar la variable antes de x a $x para que no tenga el problema de variable no definida.